# keep the nginx logs of the last 30 days

Tags: nginx, logging, ubuntu-16.04

I want to keep the nginx logs of the lsat 30 days. 
The default configuration is 15 days, as the image shows.
[image]

I would like to keep the last 30 days instead.

Here are the looging settings of nginx:

```
    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

But it doesn't say anything about "how oft" it should be taken.

I'm not a nginx expert at all, so I don't know how/where I can change that configuration.

Maybe someone there needed to do the same and want to help me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To change this behavior, you'll have to change the logrotate file of nginx.
This file is probably located in /etc/logrotate.d.
For achieving what you're trying to do, put the directives `weekly` and `rotate 30` inside the file corresponding to nginx.
After that, use the following command to ensure the changes take effect:

- `logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/nginx-config-file`

Comment: @reportingforduty wouldn't that config store log files for 30 weeks instead of the last 30 days? (rotate file each week, keep 30 files)

Comment: that sounds right, and you should simply need to swap `weekly` for `daily`

Answer (score 12):

You can set up logrotate for nginx, in this way you can maintain logs for 30 days or more as per your requirements !

```
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx


/var/log/nginx/access_log {
rotate 7
size 5k
dateext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
missingok
compress
sharedscripts
postrotate
    test -r /var/run/nginx.pid && kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
endscript
}
```

change value of #rotate accordingly ! 30,40 etc etc ...

Answer (score 4):

[Logrotate](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate) is a utility not specific to nginx that is installed by default on Ubuntu/Debian designed to ease management of log  files. You can find config info and background at the manpages:

```
man logrotate
```

On my Debian server, the config for me is stored in `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx`. The manpages give examples of config files with intuitive names. For your case you should have the lines

```
daily
rotate 30
```

Save the result with

```
sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

For a more in depth tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04